# accesstime on macOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, find, stat

Suppose you own a file system on a unix machine, and
you would like to know which of the regular files on this system
you have accessed within some interval.
("Regular file" means it is not a directory.)
Not modified, not changed their status,  merely accessed.
For instance

- You are listening to a sequence of sound files and want to know which you have already opened today.
- You are looking at the contents of text files using `grep`, `less`, or `cat`, and want to know which you have already looked into in the past 60 seconds.

On some unix systems, a command like `find . -atime -60s` will answer the question. This works on a macbook pro, purchased 2015, running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

But on a macbook pro purchased March 2020, running macOS Catalina 10.15.5, this does not work.
Recall that the `stat` command returns four distinct  "times" associated with a file:

1. accesstime or `atime`
2. modification time or `mtime`
3. time file status last changed or `ctime`
4. `birthtime`

But on the new mac, `atime` is simply identical to `ctime` for a regular file.
The difference can be seen below. In these examples, we also use `ls` to  doublecheck the `mtime`  and `ctime` values obtained from `stat`. And we see that `stat` behaves differently in the two releases of macOS.

macOS Mojave 10.14.6:

```
> ls -lT crit
-rw-r--r--  1 BNW  staff  1712 Jun 13 02:16:51 2020 crit
> ls -lTc crit
-rw-r--r--  1 BNW  staff  1712 Jun 17 18:40:25 2020 crit
> stat crit
16777220 8696326140 -rw-r--r-- 1 BNW staff 0 1712 "Jul 10 21:56:15 2020" "Jun 13 02:16:51 2020" "Jun 17 18:40:25 2020" "Jun 13 02:16:51 2020" 4096 8 0 crit
> stat -s crit
st_dev=16777220 st_ino=8696326140 st_mode=0100644 st_nlink=1 st_uid=501 st_gid=20 st_rdev=0 st_size=1712 st_atime=1594432575 st_mtime=1592029011 st_ctime=1592433625 st_birthtime=1592029011 st_blksize=4096 st_blocks=8 st_flags=0
>
```

Now with a new macbook pro, macOS Catalina 10.15.5, the `atime` value returned by `stat` is identical to the `ctime`.

```
> ls -lT z01
-rw-r--r--  1 kpr  staff  416397 Jun 16 12:03:11 2020 z01
> ls -lTc z01
-rw-r--r--  1 kpr  staff  416397 Jun 25 21:38:30 2020 z01
> stat z01
16777223 8163218 -rw-r--r-- 1 kpr staff 0 416397 "Jun 25 21:38:30 2020" "Jun 16 12:03:11 2020" "Jun 25 21:38:30 2020" "Jun 16 12:03:11 2020" 4096 816 0 z01
> stat -s z01
st_dev
```

Thus, when I use `find` on the new computer, it no longer returns the names of **regular files** recently looked at, only **directories** whose files have been recently accessed.

Was this a conscious choice by Apple developers? Why was this done? Under macos Catalina, is there some other way to find regular files by accesstime?